# How to change a data from a Anonymous query on EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I'm using Entity Framework and I have a Table Users, and a Row with a data that needs to be Decrypted, the problem is when I make a query to make a list of these users I can't directly Decrypt because is a Anonymous type..

```
 var query = context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(x => new
 {
    x.Id,
    x.FirstName,
    x.LastName,
    x.UCP
 });
 response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, query.ToList());
```

So how to change the data from UCP to a decrypted Data, I'm not asking how to Decrypt but how to Change!

Comment: `query.ToList().Select(x => new {
                    x.Id,
                    x.FirstName,
                    x.LastName,
                    UCP = Decrypt(x.UCP)
                }).ToList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(x => new
                {
                    x.Id,
                    x.FirstName,
                    x.LastName,
                    x.UCP
                })
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.Id,
                    x.FirstName,
                    x.LastName,
                    UCP = Decode(x.UCP)
                });
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, query.ToList());
```

`AsEnumerable` method is better than `ToList`, it does not create collections